# Service cannot start after putting installation function in it

Tags: c, windows, service, windows-services

I followed a tutorial (http://asawicki.info/news_1404_coding_windows_services_in_c.html) to create a basic Windows Service in C++. Here is the code I put together:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

CHAR SvcName[] = "TestSvc";
CHAR SvcDesc[] = "This is a test service";
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_ServiceStatusHandle; 
HANDLE g_StopEvent;
DWORD g_CurrentState = 0;
bool g_SystemShutdown = false;

void ReportStatus(DWORD state)
{
    g_CurrentState = state;
    SERVICE_STATUS serviceStatus = {
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
        g_CurrentState,
        state == SERVICE_START_PENDING ? 0 : SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN,
        NO_ERROR,
        0,
        0,
        0,
    };
    SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus);
}

DWORD WINAPI HandlerEx(DWORD control, DWORD eventType, void *eventData, void *context)
{
    switch (control)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        g_SystemShutdown = true;

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        ReportStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
        SetEvent(g_StopEvent);
        break;

    default:
        ReportStatus(g_CurrentState);
        break;
    }

    return NO_ERROR;
}

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    g_ServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(SvcName, &HandlerEx, NULL);

    ReportStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING);
    g_StopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    ReportStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING);

    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_StopEvent, 3000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        do_some_work(); // Just a sample function that does nothing at all
    }

    ReportStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
    CloseHandle(g_StopEvent);
    ReportStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTable[] = {
        { SvcName, &ServiceMain },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTable))
        return 0;
    else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT)
        return -1;
    else
        return -2;
}
```

This works fine if I use sc create binpath = "C:...path...\TestSvc.exe". It starts correctly and it can correctly be queried (sc query TestSvc) and stopped (sc stop TestSvc).
If I add a custom function at the beginning of the main function, and then I call TestSvc.exe install, it says it correctly installs the service but then I can not start.

```
VOID SvcInstall()
{
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
    SC_HANDLE schService;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

    if( !GetModuleFileName( NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH ) )
    {
        printf("Cannot install service (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    schSCManager = OpenSCManager( 
        NULL,                    // local computer
        NULL,                    // ServicesActive database 
        SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 

    if (NULL == schSCManager) 
    {
        printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Create the service

    schService = CreateService( 
        schSCManager,              // SCM database 
        SvcName,                   // name of service 
        SvcName,                   // service name to display 
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,        // desired access 
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, // service type 
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,      // start type 
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,      // error control type 
        szPath,                    // path to service's binary 
        NULL,                      // no load ordering group 
        NULL,                      // no tag identifier 
        NULL,                      // no dependencies 
        NULL,                      // LocalSystem account 
        NULL);                     // no password 

    if (schService == NULL) 
    {
        printf("CreateService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError()); 
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }
    else printf("Service installed successfully\n"); 

    CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}     

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if( _strcmpi( argv[1], "install") == 0 )
    {
        SvcInstall();
        return;
    }

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTable[] = {
        { SvcName, &ServiceMain },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTable))
        return 0;
    else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT)
        return -1;
    else
        return -2;
}
```

So, basically speaking, if I add the installation function, the service installs correctly but then I can not correctly start it. The error I get is that the service has not responded to the start command correctly.
What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing jumps out.  You could use regedit.exe to look at the registration.  Do consider adding the other thing that every service needs to be maintainable, add logging.

Comment: Was trying to follow without actually running - I was wondering if `g_CurrentState` is a good value when it's first used, and not `0`?

Comment: @HansPassant I added a global ofstream of a file. In every function I added a line to be put to the log file and it seems like the ServiceMain function gets never called once. This obviousely does not happen to the first version, where the log gets the lines from ServiceMain and so on. Looking at the registry, the service gets registered because the appropriate keys are created.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker afaik, it's first used after being set to a value != 0. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, looking at the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewed the article reference you provided, as well as this article: [Writing a ServiceMain Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687414(v=vs.85).aspx).

Made some subtle changes to your code based on the Microsoft article, to no avail.

Then, noticed this (original code):

```
if( _strcmpi( argv[1], "install") == 0 )
{
    SvcInstall();
    return;
}
```

and realized that with no parameters to the `.exe`, like when you would run as a service, the reference to `argv[1]` would be out-of-bounds and would effectively crash your application.

This small change:

```
if (argc > 1 && _strcmpi(argv[1], "install") == 0)
```

should fix your issue.

I'm posting your original code, in its entirety with some slight modifications, mainly influenced by the Microsoft article I've referenced, that you can take or leave as you see fit.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

CHAR SvcName[] = "TestSvc";
CHAR SvcDesc[] = "This is a test service";
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_ServiceStatusHandle;
HANDLE g_StopEvent;
DWORD g_CurrentState = 0;
bool g_SystemShutdown = false;

void ReportStatus(const DWORD state)
{
    static DWORD dwCheckPoint = 1;

    g_CurrentState = state;

    SERVICE_STATUS serviceStatus = {
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
        g_CurrentState,
        state == SERVICE_START_PENDING ? 0 : SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP,
        NO_ERROR,
        0,
        state == SERVICE_RUNNING || state == SERVICE_STOPPED ? 0 : dwCheckPoint++,
        state == SERVICE_START_PENDING ? 3000 : 0,
    };
    SetServiceStatus(g_ServiceStatusHandle, &serviceStatus);
}

DWORD WINAPI HandlerEx(DWORD control, DWORD eventType, void *eventData, void *context)
{
    switch (control)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        g_SystemShutdown = true;

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        ReportStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
        SetEvent(g_StopEvent);
        break;

    default:
        ReportStatus(g_CurrentState);
        break;
    }

    return NO_ERROR;
}

void do_some_work()
{
}

VOID SvcInstall()
{
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
    SC_HANDLE schService;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

    if (!GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH))
    {
        printf("Cannot install service (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
        NULL,                    // local computer
        NULL,                    // ServicesActive database 
        SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 

    if (NULL == schSCManager)
    {
        printf("OpenSCManager failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Create the service

    schService = CreateService(
        schSCManager,              // SCM database 
        SvcName,                   // name of service 
        SvcName,                   // service name to display 
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,        // desired access 
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, // service type 
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,      // start type 
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,      // error control type 
        szPath,                    // path to service's binary 
        NULL,                      // no load ordering group 
        NULL,                      // no tag identifier 
        NULL,                      // no dependencies 
        NULL,                      // LocalSystem account 
        NULL);                     // no password 

    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateService failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }
    else printf("Service installed successfully\n");

    CloseServiceHandle(schService);
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    g_ServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(SvcName, &HandlerEx, NULL);

    ReportStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING);
    g_StopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    ReportStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING);

    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_StopEvent, 3000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        do_some_work(); // Just a sample function that does nothing at all
    }

    ReportStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
    CloseHandle(g_StopEvent);
    ReportStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1 && _strcmpi(argv[1], "install") == 0)
    {
        SvcInstall();
        return 0;
    }

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTable[] = {
        { SvcName, &ServiceMain },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTable))
        return 0;
    else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT)
        return -1;
    else
        return -2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

&ServiceMain is the reference to function. If so then it must pass some parameters, and handler_ex return no_error instead of handle which must be passed g_ServiceStatusHandle. May be i`m wrong?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms686001(v=vs.85).aspx says that the parameter should be a pointer, that's why I used the & in front of that name. I did not understand the last part of your statement, could you explain again, please?